# assign a new value based on combinations

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these two tables

the first one has id's and a categorical variable 'code'
table1

```
    id  code
1   1     F
2   1     B
3   1     J
4   2     D
5   2     B
6   2     F
7   2     G
8   2     C
9   2     D
10  3     G
11  3     G
12  3     G
13  4     B
14  4     F
15  4     C
16  4     D
17  5     C
18  5     A
19  5     G
20  5     D
```

and table2
has some combinations of the categorical variable 'code' which are assigned a new category 'code3'

```
    code1 code2 code_3
1     C     B      O
2     B     A      K
3     A     C      L
4     E     B      N
5     A     D      J
6     D     B      L
```

id's in table1 come with multiple codes, the combinations of those codes result in new codes found on table2. 
how to I assign the id's in table1 the values in table2 code3 based on the combinations they have?

desired output

would be something like

```
 id  code
1   1     F
2   1     B
3   1     J
5   2     L      -- added, while a B and D removed 
6   2     F
7   2     G
8   2     C
...
```

Comment: Edit your question and show your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of new codes to add by doing a self-join and then joining to `table2` to find matches:

```
select t1.id, t2.code3
from table1 t1 join
     table1 tt1
     on t1.id = tt1.id and
        t1.code < t2.code join
     table2 t2
     on t2.code1 = t1.code and
        t2.code2 = tt1.code;
```

Comment: thanx for the solution , as @Stephano Zanini pointed out, the last line should  be     t2.code2 = tt1.code;

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, code, NVL (code3, code)
    FROM (SELECT id,
                 code,
                 hh,
                 rr,
                 gg,
                 code3
            FROM (  SELECT id,
                           code,
                           hh,
                           code || hh rr
                      FROM --here rr is used as foreign key which refer gg ,which can used as primary key of table2
                          (SELECT id,
                                  code,
                                  LEAD (code, 1, code)
                                     OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ROWNUM)
                                     hh
                             FROM table1)
                  ORDER BY code, hh) e, --hh gives the  code of next row of each code of table1
                 (  SELECT code1 || code2 gg, code3
                      FROM table2
                  ORDER BY code1, code2) b
           WHERE e.rr = b.gg(+))
ORDER BY id;                                                                                                                           --here left outer join is used to get desired output
    -- ORDER BY code,hh and ORDER BY code1,code2 are used to make sure that SUM(D+B)=L AND SUM(B+D)=L
```